# Cython compile error C-Libraries Tutorial

Tags: python, cython

I am currently trying to learn Cython, and started by going through their Tutorial. (Running Debian 8)
I am running into problems in the [Using C libraries](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) part.

Here are my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup 
from distutils.extension import Extension 
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = cythonize([
    Extension("queue", ["que.pyx"],
              libraries=["calg"])
    ])


setup(
      ext_modules=ext_modules )
```

que.pxd

```
cdef extern from "libcalg/queue.h":
    ctypedef struct Queue:
        pass
    ctypedef void* QueueValue

    Queue* queue_new()
    void queue_free(Queue* queue)

    int queue_push_head(Queue* queue, QueueValue data)
    QueueValue  queue_pop_head(Queue* queue)
    QueueValue queue_peek_head(Queue* queue)

    int queue_push_tail(Queue* queue, QueueValue data)
    QueueValue queue_pop_tail(Queue* queue)
    QueueValue queue_peek_tail(Queue* queue)

    bint queue_is_empty(Queue* queue)
```

and que.pyx

```
cimport que

cdef class Queue:
    cdef que.Queue* _c_queue
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._c_queue = que.cqueue_new()
        if self._c_queue is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

def __dealloc__(self):
    if self._c_queue is not NULL:
        cqueue.queue_free(self._c_queue)
```

When I try to do `python setup.py build_ext -i` it tells me the following error messages:
Compiling que.pyx because it changed.

```
[1/1] Cythonizing que.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport que

cdef class Queue:
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

que.pyx:3:5: 'Queue' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport que

cdef class Queue:
    cdef que.Queue* _c_queue
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

que.pyx:4:18: Pointer base type cannot be a Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport que

cdef class Queue:
    cdef que.Queue* _c_queue
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._c_queue = que.cqueue_new()
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

que.pyx:6:38: Cannot convert Python object to 'Queue *'

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport que

cdef class Queue:
    cdef que.Queue* _c_queue
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._c_queue = que.cqueue_new()
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

que.pyx:6:38: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        self._c_queue = que.cqueue_new()
        if self._c_queue is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

def __dealloc__(self):
    if self._c_queue is not NULL:
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

que.pyx:11:21: Invalid types for 'is_not' (Python object, void *)

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        if self._c_queue is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

def __dealloc__(self):
    if self._c_queue is not NULL:
        cqueue.queue_free(self._c_queue)
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

que.pyx:12:14: undeclared name not builtin: cqueue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    libraries=["calg"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 877, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 997, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: que.pyx
```

To me it seems like the main problems are that I redeclare some things and that a pointer cannot be converted into a python object, but I really do not know what the exact problem is.

Can somebody help me make sense of the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`que.pyx` and `que.pxd` share a namespace (if a pxd file has the same name as a pyx file then it's automatically cimported into the pyx file). Therefore Cython believes `Queue` to be both the C structure definition and your cdef class. (Under these circumstances you don't need to do `cimport que`)

You've got (at least) 3 options:

1. Rename one of the files (so the automatic cimporting into the pyx namespace doesn't happen).
2. Rename your cdef class.
3. Rename your C struct. Note that you only need to do this in Cython, you can have keep the name in C:

Code for point 3:

```
ctypedef struct c_Queue "Queue": # called c_Queue in Cython but Queue in C
    pass
```

---

You then end up with a bunch of minor error messages:

> `que.pyx:6:38: Cannot convert Python object to 'Queue *'`

Check the spelling of `que.cqueue_new()`

> `que.pyx:11:21: Invalid types for 'is_not' (Python object, void *)`

You can't use `is not` for C pointers. Use `!=`

> `que.pyx:12:14: undeclared name not builtin: cqueue`

Check the spelling.

Comment: Hi this really helped, but now i get the error that it cannot find the `libcalg/queue.h` file.
I downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/fragglet/c-algorithms/releases) did do `configure --prefix=/usr/include` `make` and `make install` but only a `libcalg.so` and no `libarlg/queue.h` file shows up.

Comment: I really don't know about that I'm afraid